# Evaluate the following integral

Tags: calculus

I wish to evaluate $$\int 3x^5e^{-\lambda x^3} dx$$

My attemt so far is as follows:

Let $$u=3x^5 \text{ and let } \frac{dv}{dx}=e^{-\lambda x^3}$$

Then we get $$\frac{du}{dx}=15x^4 \text{ and } v=\frac{e^{-\lambda x^3}}{-3\lambda x^2}$$

This then gives $$\int 3x^5e^{-\lambda x^3} dx=\frac{-x^3e^{-\lambda x^3}}{\lambda}+\int \frac{-5x^2 e^{-\lambda x^3}}{\lambda} dx$$

I can see that this isn't going to take me anywhere though. Have a made a mistake or is there just a better way to approach this?

Comment: Put $ x^3 = t $

Comment: The suggested kind of substitution is the best way to start. One could integrate by parts directly. However, if we do that your choice of $u$ and $\frac{dv}{dx}$ is not useful. Note also that the calculation of $v$ is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
Let  $$-\lambda x^3=u\implies-3\lambda x^2dx=du$$

$$\int3x^5e^{-\lambda x^3}dx=\dfrac1{\lambda^2}\int ue^u\ du$$

Use  [LIATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#LIATE_rule) rule

Answer (score 1):

The more appropriate substitution is clearly $$u = -\lambda x^3, \quad du = -3\lambda x^2 \, dx,$$ so that $$\int 3x^5 e^{-\lambda x^3} \, dx = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \int (-3 \lambda x^2) (-\lambda x^3) e^{-\lambda x^3} \, dx = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \int u e^u \, du,$$ and the remainder is performed using integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to pick
$$
u' = 3x^5 \quad v = e^{-\lambda x^3} \Rightarrow \\
u = (1/2) x^6 \quad v' = e^{-\lambda x^3}(-3\lambda x^2)
$$
But that offers another way:
$$
v' = e^{-\lambda x^3}(-3\lambda x^2) \quad u = (-1/\lambda) x^3 \Rightarrow \\
v = e^{-\lambda x^3} \quad u' = (-3/\lambda) x^2
$$
Or if $\lambda \ne 0$:
\begin{align}
\int 3x^5 \, e^{-\lambda x^3} dx 
&=
\int \underbrace{(-1/\lambda) x^3}_u \, 
\underbrace{e^{-\lambda x^3}(-3\lambda x^2)}_{v'} \, dx \\ 
&= \underbrace{(-1/\lambda)x^3}_u \underbrace{e^{-\lambda x^3}}_v -
\int \underbrace{(-3/\lambda)x^2}_{u'} \, 
\underbrace{e^{-\lambda x^3}}_v \, dx \\
&= (-1/\lambda)x^3 e^{-\lambda x^3} -
(1/\lambda^2) \int \underbrace{(-3\lambda x^2)\, e^{-\lambda x^3}}_{v'} \, dx \\
&= (-1/\lambda)x^3 e^{-\lambda x^3} -
(1/\lambda^2) e^{-\lambda x^3} \\
&= (-1/\lambda^2)(1 + \lambda x^3) e^{-\lambda x^3} 
\end{align}